# How secure is Haskell regarding protection against buffer overruns?

Tags: haskell

Does Haskell have built-in protections to avoid buffer overruns when taking input from the keyboard or reading from a file?

Comment: What's a buffer? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you don't use any `unsafe` functions, nor the FFI (interface towards C), the GHC runtime system guarantees you won't have buffer overruns.

To be pedantic, there's the possibility that you call a library which implements a safe function using an `unsafe` function in an incorrect way, triggering a buffer overrun, but that's rather unlikely since there are relatively few libraries that exploit `unsafe` functions, and those are usually heavily tested.

For completeness, the GHC runtime could also have its own bugs, but -again- that's unlikely.

When we write Haskell code, we commonly pretend these `unsafe` functions do not exist.